# Why is malloc assigning an already allocated memory position?

Tags: c, malloc

I know that malloc should use a not allocated memory when called multiple times unless it has been previously freed. However is not working here, any help here would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct thread_params
{
    char *str;
};

void *threadFunc(void* parameters)
{
    struct thread_params* p = (struct thread_params*) parameters;

    printf("Working with pointer %p\n", &p->str);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
        pthread_t tid;
        struct thread_params thread_args;
        char *a = malloc(sizeof(char));
        thread_args.str = a;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &threadFunc, &thread_args);
        pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
Working with pointer 0x7ffeec881b28
Working with pointer 0x7ffeec881b28
```

the same pointer

Comment: How about trying `&thread_args[i]`

Comment: Guys, this program does not have a race, that's what the `pthread_join` is for. I also do not see undefined behaviour (neither do UBsan and TSAN), it's just leaking `a`s, but everything is as it should.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to refer to different `thread_args` you would need an array of them. Also, you most likely want to print the pointer at `str` and not the `&address` of that pointer.

There's only one `thread_args` and you're just printing the address of one of it's members (a pointer). Not the value of that pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct thread_params
{
    char *str;
};

void *threadFunc(void* parameters)
{
    struct thread_params* p = (struct thread_params*) parameters;

    printf("Working with pointer %p\n", p->str);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
        pthread_t tid;
        struct thread_params thread_args;
        char *a = malloc(sizeof(char));
        thread_args.str = a;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &threadFunc, &thread_args);
        pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `thread_args` needs to be declared outside the `for` loop, otherwise the scope ends when the loop repeats.

Comment: thread_args is not part of the problem. Only the mistake in the print-function is.

Comment: LOL,  The two correct answers both have down votes, and my partially correct answer has an upvote.  Strange.

Comment: thread_args does become important for it to be useful in my actual code though, thank you both

Answer (score 2):

To print the address of your malloc'ed memory, do

```
  printf("Working with pointer %p\n", p->str);
```

The code you have is not printing the address of the memory returned by malloc(), it is printing the address of the `str` variable within the `thread_params` struct.
That address is likely to be the same each time since the location of your `thread_args` variable probably does not change between the loop iterations.

Note that without your `pthread_join()` call, you would pass in a pointer to the new thread to a variable that goes out of scope on the next iteration of your loop, which would cause undefined behavior, so be aware of the lifetime of whatever you pass into `pthread_create`

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing the address returned by `malloc()`. You're printing `&p->str`, which is the address of the structure member. The compiler is using the same memory for the structure each time through the loop, so the address of the `str` member doesn't change.

Change `&p->str` to `p->str` and you'll print the address returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score -1):

Nice one :-) In your `printf` statement, you have `&p->str` --- how about `p->str` instead?

This will get you:

`Working with pointer 0x6020000000b0
Working with pointer 0x6020000000d0`

which seems more reasonable. Before, you were getting the address of where the struct-member is in memory, I think.

Comment: It shows the same address of `a` from the loop and ` p ` from thread function.

Comment: @mayur But you're running a different program!